# Non-bijective endomorphisms of finite groups

Tags: group-theory

How can I prove that there are no finite groups $G$ where there exists an endomorphism $G\rightarrow G$ that is injective but not surjective, or other way round?

Comment: This has nothing to do with groups. The statement is true for all maps from a finite set to itself.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a finite set and $f:X \to X$ is any function, then the conditions below are equivalent:

- $f$ is bijective
- $f$ is injective
- $f$ is surjective

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989043/rigorous-proof-that-surjectivity-implies-injectivity-for-finite-sets for proofs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem about groups but a general fact about sets:

Let $E, F$ be finite sets such that $\lvert E\rvert=\lvert F\rvert$, and $f\colon E\rightarrow F$. The following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective;
2. $f$ is surjective;
3. $f$ is bijective.

   (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): If $f$  is injective, $\lvert f(E)\rvert=\lvert E\rvert=\lvert F\rvert$, hence $f(E)=F$, which means $f$ is surjective.
   (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) by contraposition: if $f$ is not injective, it can't be surjective since $\lvert f(E)\rvert<\lvert E\rvert=\lvert F\rvert$.

Since (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2), it is trivial both are equivalent to (3).