# Counting the number of injective and surjective functions from a set to itself

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I have a question about counting the number of injective (one-to-one) and surjective (onto) functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself that satisfy $|f(i)-i| \leq 1, \forall i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$. I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance and happy new year to you all

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to solve the problem by creating a recursive sequence but I couldn't figure out how to create the sequence. Mr JMoravitz gave an interesting solution to the problem below ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ is a function from a finite set to itself and it is surjective, then it is necessarily also injective.

If $f$ is a function from a finite set to itself and it is injective, then it is necessarily also surjective.

See [Rigorous proof that surjectivity implies injectivity for finite sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989043/rigorous-proof-that-surjectivity-implies-injectivity-for-finite-sets)

Both questions are then the same and we are asked to count the number of *bijections* from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to itself.

Now... note that the **only** choice for $f(1)$ is $1$ or $2$.

In the case that $f(1)=2$, since $f$ must be a bijection, $f(2)\neq 2$.  This leaves $f(2)=1$ or $f(2)=3$.  Note, however, that if $f(2)=3$, then $f(n)=1$ for some $n\geq 3$ which is a contradiction since that would imply $|f(n)-n|=|1-n|\geq 2$.  Thus, if $f(1)=2$ then $f(2)=1$.

Continue via a recurrence relation using the previous observation.

Letting $a_n=$#of bijective functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to itself, from the earlier observation we have the recurrence  $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with initial conditions $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$.

You should then recognize this as being the fibonacci sequence and can find the closed form using traditional methods if you so choose.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am having trouble extrapolating the recurrence relation. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Made some progress : f(n) has two possibilities n or n-1. When f(n) = n then f maps {1,....,n-1} to {1,....,n-1}, which gives me $a_{n-1}$ part of the recurrence relation. However i m having trouble when f(n) equals n-1.

Comment: @JaiT if f maps n to n-1, what options are available for n-1 to map to?  Remember that the function must be bijective.

Comment: if f = n-1 then maps {1,...,n-1} to {1,...,n-2,n} ?

Comment: Incorrect, try again.  What is the preimage of $n$?

Comment: @JaiT I will point out that this entire argument was already explained in my post in the only paragraph that was 3 lines long, except i described it using the first two instead of the last two terms.  If $f(n)=n$ then we use one of our desired bijections with restriction from $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ and this can be done in $a_{n-1}$ ways.  If $f(n)=n-1$ then $f(n-1)=n$ because there are no other candidates for a preimage to $n$ and so the remaining $\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}$ map to $\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}$, and that can be done in $a_{n-2}$ ways