# Definition of terms for functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Hi I have this question from my homework and I'm stuck on it. It says:

Let X and Y be sets.
Suppose that X is finite and let f : X → Y be a map. Show that f is injective if and only if |f(X)| = |X|.

Firstly what do the modulus signs around f(X) mean and what does id_X mean in terms of functions.

Ok thanks for the quick responses. So in the question where it says "|f(X)| = |X|" does that mean the number of elements in f(X)= to the number of elements in X

Comment: $|X|$ is the *cardinality* of the set $X$ : when $X$ is *finite* it is simply the number of elements of $X$.

Comment: What if X was infinite

Comment: $\text {id}_X$ is the *identity* function on the set $X$, i.e. the function that maps every $x \in X$ into itself.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/989059/589.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus signs mean "the size of", or "the cardinality of". For instance, $|\{1,2,7,10\}|=4$.

If $X$ is infinite, then $|X|$ still works; there are infinite cardinalities. Beware, though. Intuition might not be your friend any more when dealing with infinite cardinalities.

$\operatorname{Id}_X$ is the unique function $X\to X$ given by $\operatorname{Id}_X(x)=x$. It's called the *identity function* on $X$.