# Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that if there is a bijection between $\{1,..,n\}$ and $\{1,..,m\}$ then $n=m$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*My try for the question*:

Let $X,Y$ be subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a bijection function with $\operatorname{Card}(X)=n,\operatorname{Card}(Y)=m$ both in $\mathbb{N}$. I think that If we show Card$(X)$=Card$(Y)$ then we are done. So, how? Can you give a hint?

Comment: Body of question is unclear. What are $X$ and $Y$? How do $m$ and $n$ get involved? Body appears to have no relation to subject line, which is a perfectly clear question.

Comment: @user4894 Actually, the question is ''Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that if there is a bijection between $n$ and $m$ then $n=m$.'' The body is my thinks that you are right, it is not clear.

Comment: How does a bijection between natural numbers make sense?

Comment: @JonathanHebert If the function is injective and surjective than it is bijective between natural numbers,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Functions are between sets. If $f$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, where $X$ is a set of cardinality $n$ and $Y$ is a set of cardinality $m$, then it is true that $n=m $. Surely, that's what you're trying to prove? "A bijection between $n$ and $m$" does not have any meaning, it's gibberish.

Comment: @JonathanHebert So, what should I try for proof?

Comment: @kahler I can find a bijective function with $n$ and $m$ s.t. $f(n)=m$ however this doesn't necessarily mean $m=n$. Example: $f(x)=x+m-n$. It what you mean by a bijection between $m$ and $n$. As these are numbers the statement makes no sense. A bijection is between a set of numbers and if we have the set of ${n}$ and ${m}$, that especially doesn't mean $n=m$.

Comment: I edited, to try to clarify the question. I think this is what's Kahler want. Please let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Again, I'm trying now: Assume Card$(X)=n$ and Card$(Y)=m$. Since $f$ bijection $f$ is also injection clearly then Card$(X)\leq$ Card$(Y)$. So, since $f$ is bijective then $f^{-1}$ is injective then Card$(X)\geq$ Card$(Y)$. Hence, Card$(X)$=Card$(Y)$.I.e., $n=m$, Is it true?

Comment: @zwim Can you check my last comment?

Comment: Yes that's what we need!!! thanks

Comment: @Sentinel135 that is, my last comment is enough for proof, isn't it?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189220/589.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Actually, in ZFC natural numbers are canonically identified with a specific subset of ordinals. Specifically $$0=\emptyset \\ 1=\{\emptyset\} \\ 2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} \\ \vdots\\ n+1=n\cup\{n\}$$ So a bijection between $n,m\in\Bbb N$ can make sense: it's not gibberish at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f^{-1}$ is injective, it suffices to prove that if there is an injection $f : X \to Y$ then $\mathrm{Card}(X) \le \mathrm{Card}(Y)$. This can be done by induction on $\mathrm{Card}(X)$, and is fairly tedious.

The base case is simple, since in this case $X=\varnothing$, whose cardinality is less than or equal to the cardinality of any other set.

For the induction step, fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that, whenever there exists an injection $f : X' \to Y'$ with $\mathrm{Card}(X') = n$, then $\mathrm{Card}(X') \le \mathrm{Card}(Y')$. Take a set $X$ of cardinality $n+1$ and suppose $f : X \to Y$ is an injection; you need to use the induction hypothesis to prove that $\mathrm{Card}(X) \le \mathrm{Card}(Y)$.

To do this, take an element $x_0 \in X$; note this exists since $\mathrm{Card}(X) > 0$. Prove that:

- $f$ restricts to a (well-defined!) injection $f' : X \setminus \{ x_0 \} \to Y \setminus \{ f(x_0) \}$.
- Deduce that $\mathrm{Card}(X \setminus \{ x_0 \}) \le \mathrm{Card}(Y \setminus \{ f(x_0) \})$. To do this, you will need to prove the more general fact that if $A$ is a set and $a \in A$ then $\mathrm{Card}(A \setminus \{ a \}) = \mathrm{Card}(A) - 1$.
- Deduce that $\mathrm{Card}(X) \le \mathrm{Card}(Y)$.

This will complete the proof.

Comment: This can also be proven by contradiction. Suppose that $n > m$. Note that we can index all the elements in $X$ and $Y$ such that $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n \in X$, and $y_1,y_2,\dots y_m \in Y$  where $f(x_k)=y_k$. As $m<n \in \mathbb N$ there must exist an $x_{m+1}\in X$, This implies there also exists $f(x_{m+1})=y_{m+1}\in Y$. Since $f$ is injective $f(x_j)\neq f(x_k)$ if $j\neq k$ for all $j,k \in \mathbb N$. Thus $$x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3 \dots \neq x_m \neq x_{m+1}\in X \Rightarrow y_1\neq y_2\neq y_3\dots \neq y_m \neq y_{m+1}\in Y.$$ Which in turn implies that $Card(Y)> m$, a contradiction.

Comment: addendum it's for $j,k \leq n \in N$ as the $Card(X)=n$

Comment: You have to be careful reasoning about enumerations of sets, because you're essentially reasoning about bijections. This is a subtle point: the issue is that if you want to claim that given an injection $X \to Y$ and enumerations $\{ x_i \}$ and $\{ y_i \}$ of $X$ and $Y$, you need to prove that it's possible to enumerate $Y$ in such a way that $y_1=f(x_1)$ and so on. When you say "where $f(x_k)=y_k$", you already arrive at a contradiction, since $f(x_n)=y_n$, but this makes no sense since $Y$ is only enumerated up to $y_m$ and $m<n$.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention Your proof requires that $f^{-1}$ exists which you don't seem to prove. Which would constitute about 50% of the proof don't you think?  Also you assumed that $f^{-1}$ to be injective. Hmm...

Comment: The take-home is that to prove that it's even *possible* to enumerate $X$ and $Y$ in such a way that $f(x_k)=y_k$ for $1 \le k \le n$, you ultimately need to have proved (an equivalent formulation of) the result I mention in my answer.

Comment: @Sentinel135: That $f^{-1}$ exists is because $f$ is a bijection. If you like, rename all the "injective" $f$s to $g$s - the fact that I used the same symbol is immaterial. Since the OP's function $f$ is bijective (hence injective), this claim with $g=f$ shows $\mathrm{Card}(X) \le \mathrm{Card}(Y)$; since $f^{-1}$ is injective,  the same proof applied when $g=f^{-1}$ shows that $\mathrm{Card}(Y) \le \mathrm{Card}(X)$.

Comment: No I need to be careful in stating that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are unique elements in $Y$. I clearly did that when I dealt with the injectiveness of $f$. I never assumed that $y_1\neq y_2$ until that point. I was just indexing the $f(x)$'s for clearer reading. we can easily substitute all the $y_k$'s for $f(x_k)$'s and it would generally be the same proof.

Comment: @Sentinel135: You've misunderstood my point, but the comments section of this post isn't the place to discuss it, so I think I'll stop engaging now. The point is that if you claim that $f(x_k)=y_k$ for each $k$ (where $x_k,y_k$ are enumerations of of $X$ and $Y$), then you've already assumed the result. (I teach this stuff to undergrads and this is a mistake they make often, and it takes a long time to explain the root of the error, which I can't do in an MSE comments thread, sorry.)

Comment: The thing is for the existence of $f^{-1}$ to exist you need to prove that the cardinality of sets are the same in bijections. Which in turn would be circle logic. Well unless you use an axiom or define a bijection such that the existence would be assumed.

Comment: @Sentinel135: That's not at all true. The proof that bijections have inverses isn't sensitive to the cardinalities of the sets involved - the same proof works for arbitrary sets, be they finite or infinite, and the proof doesn't refer to their cardinalities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55505/discussion-between-sentinel135-and-clive-newstead).

Comment: I am confused, for card(X) to be well defined, don't you actually need to know that there is no bijection between N<=n and N<=m for n neq m. (Otherwise card(X) could be equal to m or n). But this is what you want to show.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this very nice answer. I am confused, I think, in the same way which @lalala is confused. How does showing $Card(\{1,...,m\}) = Card(\{1,...,n\})$ suffice, when we are (at least as far as I can tell) using this very theorem to show that $Card$ is well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

Note that If $f$ is injective then $Card(X) \leq Card(Y)$ as $f$ is one to one so there can be more in $Y$. Also note that $f$ is surjective, this implies that $x\in X$ maps to $y\in Y$ for all $y\in Y$. So, $Card(X) \geq Card(Y)$. Since $Card(X)=n$ and $Card(Y)=m$, we have
$$n\geq m \leq n$$
which implies
$$n=m$$ as desired.

Comment: Your claim that "as $f$ is one to one, there [are more elements] in $Y$" requires a proof - the intuitive argument is all well and good, but it isn't a proof. Proving this claim constitutes 90% of the proof that bijections preserve cardinality.

Comment: The same can be said about the claim with surjection as well. If I was trying to do this rigorously I would first prove the two lemma's. But I wanted to leave that up to the reader, as I assumed this was something they were trying to prove, like for an homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

We first consider a set $X$ such that there exists a bijective function $g:\{1,...,n\}\to X$.

If there exists a bijective function $f:\{1,...,m\}\to \{1,...,n\}$, then $g\circ f:{\{1,...,m\}\to X}$ is also bijective since the composition of bijection functions is a bijection (which can be easily proved by the fact that bijective functions have two side inverses.)

Finally, follows from the definition of cardinality, we can conclude that $|X|=n=m$