# $f : [m] \to [n]$ Prove $m=n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a bijection from $[m]$ to $[n]$. Prove that $m=n$.

Induction: $n=0$

In this case $[n]= \emptyset$. A function from $A$ to $\emptyset$ is only defined if  $A = \emptyset$. Hence $m=0$.

How do I show that $m=n$, do I have to show the inverse of $f$?

Comment: What are [m], [n]? Do you mean finite sets?

Comment: But then the notation in your post like $n=[\emptyset]$ and $n=0$ at the same time is a bit wired..

Comment: @YujieZha it think its just cardinaltity so [n] is the cardinality of n

Comment: @YujieZha it should be $[n] = \emptyset$.

Comment: This is unclear. What is empty cardinality?

Comment: @AndresMejia in my note it shows [$\emptyset$]=0 but in the txtbook its whar Symlic said

Comment: Usually we use $|\{ ... \}|$to denote cardinality, so e.g. You could denote the cardinality of an empty set as $|\emptyset|$, other example $|\{1,2,3\}|$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189220/589.

Comment: @YujieZha oh k thanks

Comment: @YujieZha how do i show m=n

Comment: The question would make more sense if $[n]$ means $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: @TheGamer I think Hagen's answer solves your question. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try induction on $m$:

Assume $f\colon [m]\to[n]$ bijective. If $m=0$, then $f$ is bijective iff $n=0$.

Assume $m>0$ and $m=m'+1$. Clearly, $n>0$, so $n=n'+1$.
Now $f\restriction_{[m']}$ is a bijection $[m']\to[n]\setminus\{f(m)\}$. By a simple transposition, we find a bijection $g\colon [n]\setminus\{f(m)\}\to [n']$ and hence a bijection $g\circ f\restriction_{[m']}\colon [m']\to[n']$. By induction hypothesis, $m'=n'$ and hence $m=n$.

Answer (score 2):

*possible hint:* Let $m>n$ and show that$f:[m] \to [n]$ cannot be injective by the pigeonhole principle.

By symmetry suppose that $m<n$. if $f$ were bijective, it would have an inverse $g:[n] \to [m]$. For the same reason, this map cannot be injective.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $[m]$ is a set of $m$ elements, you might try to prove this by contrapositive.

Suppose $m \neq n$, try to prove any function $f: [m] \to [n]$ is not a bijection.