# Let $S$ and $T$ be two finite sets and $f: S \to T$ a function. Assume there is $m$ elements in $S$ and $n$ elements in $T$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be two finite sets and $f: S\to T$ a function. Assume there is $m $ elements in $S$ and $n$ elements in $T$.

Assume that $m > n$, and show that f cant be a injective function

I have written the definition, but having trouble with the mathematical argument

Comment: Are you supposed to use Peano's axioms or something like that?

Comment: I have only been in college for 5 weeks, we have not learned Peano's axioms.. looking in my book we have  really been through  the definitions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189220/589.

Answer (score 0):

a) If there would exist a surjective function, then some of two from $T$ would be the images of the same element from $S$ (by pigeonhole principle). But then this would not be function, since some element in $S$ has two images.