# Proving a function is bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra

My problem is: Let $A$ and $B$ finite sets of equal cardinality. Show that if a function $f : A \to B$ is injective then it is also surjective. Similarly show that if $f$ is surjective, then it is also injective.

My thought is since the number of elements in $|A| = |B|$, function $f: A \to B$ is bijection. But my instructor said I have to explain more. Please help me with this. I don't know how a injective function leads to a surjective function and vice versa. Thank you.

Comment: The nice thing about finite cardinality is you can do standard inductions with them.

Comment: when you wrote "if  |A| = |B|, then f: A->B is bijection" is just to rewrite the same question, is not its proof

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189220/589.

Comment: @vnsoshi, Just because they both have finite cardinality, does not mean that they have the **same** cardinality. Injectivity would give you that $|A| \leq |B|.$