# If we know that there's an injective function from A to B, how can we prove that $|A| \leq |B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to show something similar to: [$|A| \leq |B|$ iff there is an injective map from A to B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820099/a-leq-b-iff-there-is-an-injective-map-from-a-to-b), but for all sets.

I'm using the definition of cardinality that just states that $|A|$ is equal to some cardinal $k$, such that $k$     $\approx$ A (equinumerous).

I've already shown that if $|A| \leq |B|$, then there must be an injective function from A to B. Now I'm trying to prove that if there is an injective function, $|A| \leq |B|$.

I've tried to use the Axiom of Choice, that every set has a well-order, in order to show that A and B have order types of some ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and then study the different possibilities of comparisons between them; but I can't really think how that might be relevant to cardinality and showing that $|A| \leq |B|$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of $|A| \leq |B|$ (as opposed to $|A| = |B|$)?

Comment: You must have a definition of $|A| \le |B|$ you are using. What is it?

Comment: The meaning of $|A|\leq |B|$ is not clear. But I will try to help, since there's an injective function $f:A\to B$, and $f(A)\subseteq B$ we have $\overline{f}:A\to f(A)$ is a bijection, then $A\sim f(A)$. Therefore $|A|=|f(A)|\leq |B|$.

Comment: I am assuming that $A$ and $B$ each have a finite number of elements.  Suppose that $A$ has more elements than $B$.  Then, for any mapping from $A$ to $B$, there must be two distinct elements in $A$ that map to the same element in $B$.  Therefore, when $A$ has more elements than $B$, it is impossible for any mapping from $A$ to $B$ to be injective.

Comment: @coffeemath I'm working with the assumption that, if $|A| = k$ and $|B| = j$, where k and j are cardinals, and $|A| \leq |B|$, then k < j or k = j. Or to put it another way, since k and j are cardinals and thus ordinals, k $\in$ j or k = j. Not sure if this is an alright way to think about it though.

Comment: @anomaly I'm working with the assumption that, if |A|=k and |B|=j, where k and j are cardinals, and |A|≤|B|, then k < j or k = j. Or to put it another way, since k and j are cardinals and thus ordinals, k ∈ j or k = j. Not sure if this is an alright way to think about it though

Comment: In that case, take a look at the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem (or its proof).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets, $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are cardinals, and $f \colon A \to \kappa$ and $g \colon B \to \lambda$ are bijections.

*Claim*: $\kappa \subseteq \lambda$ if and only if there exists an injection $h \colon A \to B$.

$\implies$: Let $\iota \colon \kappa \to \lambda$ be the inclusion map. Then $g^{-1} \circ \iota \circ f$ is an injection from $A$ to $B$.

$\impliedby$: Cardinals are linearly ordered by inclusion, so either $\kappa \subseteq \lambda$ or $\lambda \subseteq \kappa$. If the former occurs, then we're done. If $\lambda \subseteq \kappa$, then as in the "$\implies$" direction above there is an injection $j \colon B \to A$. Applying the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, we can conclude that there is a bijection from $A$ onto $B$ (thus a bijection from $\kappa$ onto $\lambda$), and hence we in fact have $\lambda = \kappa$ (since we're talking about cardinals here and not just ordinals), so $\kappa \subseteq \lambda$ as desired.