# Prove, if  is surjective function, then  is injective function.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question would be:

**Let  – finite set, and : → .
Prove, if  is a surjective function, then  is an injective function**.

Proposed solution:

Consider f is not an injective function. Then,
it exist a, b: a not equal to b, f(a) = f(b)
This means, that at least two different elements become the same after applying
f. As U is finite, at least one element in U have an empty preimage. This is an
contradiction in case of f is a surjective function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, and your solution looks correct!

Comment: I would say: the intuition is correct, but the proof may or may not be acceptable, depending on the level of rigor expected.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989059/589