# Cardinalities of the two sets and the condition of the function in between

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So if I have two sets A and B and if |A| = |B| and if function *f* is a function from A to B and is injective, how can I prove that it is also surjective?

Forgot to mention.  A and B are finite sets.

Comment: Think about the map $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ where $$f(x)=x+1$$It's injective but not surjective. The claim is only true if $|A|<\infty$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63072/surjectivity-implies-injectivity) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989043/rigorous-proof-that-surjectivity-implies-injectivity-for-finite-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1).