Is $g: I_n\longrightarrow I_n$ injective if and only if it is surjective?
edited
Recently I'm trying to prove that given a finite set $X$, a function $f: X\longrightarrow X$ is injective if and only if it is surjective. And as part of that proof I came to the conclusion that I must prove the following:

$g: I_n\longrightarrow I_n$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.

To do this I will use a lemma and a theorem that I have already proved previously

Lemma 1. If $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is an injective function, then $f: X \longrightarrow f(X)$ is a bijection.
Theorem 1. Let $A\subset I_n$. If there exists a bijection $f: A \longrightarrow I_n$, then $A=I_n$.

I will proceed to show my progress of the demonstration of the above in quotation marks.
If $g$ is injective, then by Lemma 1, $g: I_n \longrightarrow g(I_n)$ is a bijection, then it has an inverse function $g^{-1}: g(I_n) \longrightarrow I_n$ which will also be a bijection, also $g(I_n) \subset I_n$ and by Theorem 1 it is concluded that $g(I_n)=I_n$, that is, $g$ is surjective.
If $g$ is surjective, then it has a right inverse, let $h:I_n \longrightarrow I_n$ be the right inverse of $g$, that is, $g(h(w))=w$ for all $w\in I_n$. Furthermore note that $h$ is injective, since considering $w_1$, $w_2\in I_n$ such that $h(w_1)=h(w_2)$, then $w_1=g(h(w_1))=g(h(w_2))=w_2$. Then we have that $h: I_n \longrightarrow I_n$ is injective, and from what has been demonstrated above, it implies that $h$ is surjective. Now, let $x_1$,$x_2\in I_n$ such that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$. Then there will exist $y_1$,$y_2\in I_n$ such $h(y_1)=x_1$ and $h(y_2)=x_2$, so we have that
$$y_1=g(h(y_1))=g(x_1)=g(x_2)=g(h(y_2))=y_2$$
finally, since $y_1=y_2$, then $x_1=h(y_1)=h(y_2)=x_2$. It is concluded that $g$ is injective.
I just edited my demo, found a way around the complications. Any comments or is the demonstration correct? Thank you very much for the answers.

English is not my native language either, but it is de facto international and you will get answers and comments from more people, if/when you translate your post into it.

I appreciate your comments. I apologize for the situation and have already edited the question to an English and Spanish version so that language is not a barrier to sharing mathematics.

I think you can put the english part first (and the spanish part is not really necessary)

I understand. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

I'm guessing that $I_n$ is some set with exactly $n$ elements... ? For example, ${1,2,\ldots,n}$?

Yes. I forgot to mention that $I_n={m\in \mathbb{N}\mid 1\leq m\leq n}$

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989059/589

The second part does not work because, despite $x$ is chosen arbitrary at the beginning, the function $h$ you define depends on $x$. You should call it $h_x$ for example, to avoid ambiguities. From here, your proof doesn't work.
If you want to prove that $g$ surjective implies $g$ injective, start by defining,
$$
h : x \mapsto \min\{y \in I_n|g(y) = x\}.
$$
This time, $h$ doesn't depend on a particular element of $I_n$. If is well-defined because non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ all have a minimum and you see easily that for all $x \in I_n$, $g(h(x)) = x$.
In particular, $h$ is injective because $g \circ h$ is. By the first point you proved (injective from $I_n$ to itself implies surjective), $h$ is a bijection. Therefore, the equality $g(h(x)) = x$ for all $x$ means that $g = h^{-1}$ is also bijective.

Thank you very much for the reply. I will analyze it and when I manage to fine-tune the demonstration I will edit the post.
